# Exporting multiple point shapefiles from one file using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, export, batch

I have a point shapfile of species records (about 100 species), with many georefenced ecords for each species.

I'd like to export one point shapfile for each species. 
I can do it by selecting by attributes each species and export handly every single file but it is time consumig.

Is there any possibility to batch export all the files with the same operation using QGIS?

I'm a beginner not used to Python.

Answer (score 7):

In QGIS, you can find a tool in Vector/Data Management Tools/Split Vector Layer.

There you can define the column containing the species information as Unique ID field and it will generate a new file for each category in the output directory.

Comment: Make sure your species names are normalized *before* running `split vector layer` (IE all records for one species are have the identical species name - no variation in spelling, abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation or spacing). Otherwise each species will be split up into as many files as there are variants.

Comment: It works. The batch mode option should work but it is more time consuming. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can use the tool `extract by attribute` in batch modus. Filling out the batches still might be time consuming.

[image]